# Java connectivity to database

Tags: java, mysql

I am beginner in Java. I am making a program in which i am trying to connect java to mysql database but when i add these:

```
String Name=t1.getText();
String Mobile=t2.getText();
String Email=t3.getText();

 try
     {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con=(Connection)
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","sagar");
         Statement stmt=(Statement)con.createStatement();

       String insert="INSERT INTO contact VALUES('"+Name+"','"+Moblie+"''"+Email+"');";
       stmt.executeUpdate(insert);



     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage() ,"Error", 1);

     }
```

I got lots and lots of error above and below the code, even in the declared values.

Please suggest something, in my school book nothing is given about that.

Comment: post the lots and lots of error!

Comment: ` i got lots and lots of error above and below the code`, please specify the errors

Comment: If its `lots and lots` of errors... are you sure your braces are not messed up? Verify your braces in your program. And what type of errors? Compiletime or Runtime?

Comment: on an additional note, concatenating string inside an SQL query will make your app prone to SQL injection attacks. Recommend you do some validations before the concact, if you are not already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your data source URL is incorrect, try changing it to below. host name and port should be separated by `:`,

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
```

Comment: actually dear this error is only in this post, sorry, in actual program i used the code that you mentioned. errors are not in this code, errors are shown in the code that are not written by me

Comment: @SagarSingh please attach the error "screenshot" so that we can find whats the error. Otherwise from the code point of view, your code is correct. So there may be some import, some brace misplacement error. SO, either post your code or post your error screenshot.